# Creating JSON not making more than 1 item in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

json file in php the problem iam facing is the output is only creating one item at a time i require a list of items in the json.

my code :

```
$jsonarr = array('id' => '', 'source' => $source, 
    'time_date' => $timeunix, 'title' => $titler, 
    'description' => $description, 
    'link' => $linkr,'image' => $imageurl);

for ($x = 0; $x <= count($jsonarr); $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
    echo json_encode($jsonarr);
    $fp = fopen('aaa.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($jsonarr));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

the output im getting is

```
{"id":"","source":"BBC News - Politics","time_date":1422633420,"title":"'Train everyone' for digital world","description":"People everywhere need to adapt to a world being rapidly changed by digital technology, a leading academic says.","link":"http:\/\/www.bbc.co.uk\/news\/uk-wales-politics-31049769#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&amp;ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa","image":"http:\/\/news.bbcimg.co.uk\/media\/images\/80673000\/jpg\/_80673268_glasses_bbc.jpg"}
```

this is correct but i need all the items to be added to the json not just one.

Any suggestions would be gratefully appreciated . Thanks

Comment: You need to `fopen` and `fclose` outside the loop. You should probably build an array of results and write them once outside the loop, too.

Comment: your code is writing the same encoded array several times. what is the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. The exprected output is to show all the columns from the database into a json file, im only getting the same array each time.. i put the fopen and fclose outside the loop and it creates the array multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a string and append each item to the string and write that string to a file

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC");
$jsonString = '';
foreach ($results as $value) {
$id = '"ID":"'.trim($value['ID']).'"';
$artist = '"Artist":"'.trim($value['ArtistName']).'"';
$title = '"AlbumTitle":"'.trim($value['AlbumTitle']).'"';
$items = "\n\t{\n\t\t$id,\n\t\t$artist,\n\t\t$title\n\t},";
$jsonString = $jsonString .$items;
}
$jsonString = rtrim($jsonString,",");
file_put_contents("jsonfile.json", $jsonString);
```

Comment: Thank you il give this a go